# Metadata API Case-Sensitive?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata

**is the Metadata API Case-Sensitive?**

*Scenario:* 
Take for instance the following scenario: a multi-org strategy where all development is being done on a Sandbox related to Org ABC. From that Sandbox on Org ABC, deployments will be done towards Org DEF, GHI, ... (towards another Sandbox of course).

Strict rules should be followed which could, for instance, result in creating certain features from this centralised Development Org ABC. For example: a new page layout which should be pushed from Development Org ABC towards Org DEF, GHI, ... If that page layout has the following name: XYZ123_Object_PageLayout (which follows a certain naming convention), but a developer couldn't wait for the deployment push towards Org DEF and decides to recreate that page layout. On Org DEF, he makes a mistake in the name: xyz123_Object_pagelayout (notice the case-sensitive difference).

Could this create issues during deployments?

I would assume not since Apex is case-insensitive. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I assume API names are case insensitive, but I can't find proof of that. Usage of API Names in other tooling can still be case sensitive, ie. Data Loader.

Comment: Hi Peter, I was thinking the same. There is nothing in the documentation stating is case-sensitive. So I'm also thinking here down the line of the tool creating the issues.

Comment: Which tool do you use for deployments?

Comment: Hi Peter, it's an in-house application created by a partner of ours. I just wanted to verify that this issue could not be due to the API but would be related to the app in use.